# Creating a sign-up form (similar to mailchimp) for a website page that is hosted using AWS (S3 bucket specifically)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-route53

I have created a web-page using Bootstrap, which is hosted on the web thanks to AWS S3 bucket and Route 53.

I want to add a sing-up form similar to the forms created by providers like Mailchimp - from scratch (or with the help of existing frameworks).

The the questions boils down to:

1. How can I create a a function where when a submit button is pressed, the names and email fields are saved onto a database?
2. How can I create a automatic autoresponding "welcome" message to those who signed up?
3. How can I get this to function with AWS?

Perhaps question 1 and 2 are broad and Q3 can't be answered till 1&2 are answered. If so, do link some resources that will help me learn this specifically?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [help] so you can understand the guidelines of the site. This question is really considered too broad for Stack Overflow. This site is meant for specific questions. If you are looking for resources like you mentioned, I'd recommend doing some research on Google and such. There is a lot of great information out there to help you! But Stack Overflow isn't really the place for this type of question.

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using AWS, I would suggest the fastest way to achieve this would be to use the AWS Cognito hosted UI.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-integration.html

Cognito takes care of authentication and the saving of user details. It then calls your application back. All you need to do is create a landing page to handle the callback from Cognito.